# How to output result of vim commands to shell

Tags: bash

Let's say I'm in the shell (`bash`) and want to see output that `:scriptnames` would give, but don't want to start vim or maybe I want to echo that into another file.

So I execute

```
vim +scriptnames
```

Which shows me all the scripts, but how do I echo that into the shell's stdout?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That happens, because usually Vim switches to the alternate screen and works there. Upon exiting, Vim will switch back and therefore you don't see anything left from your Vim session, but the result of the command executed even before starting Vim.

This feature is explained at `:h xterm-screens` [(link)](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tips.txt.html#xterm-screens)

So you basically don't want that and therefore want to disable that. You can do so, by setting `:set t_ti= t_te=` the terminal codes that perform this to empty.

Putting it all together, you would want to start Vim like this:

`vim -c ':set t_ti= t_te= nomore' -c 'scriptnames|q!'`

We are resetting the `'more'` option, so that you don't see the hit-enter-prompt.

Comment: This is AWESOME, thank you so much! I actually doubted this was possible.

Comment: Does this makes it possible to use VimL as a full-fledged system scripting language by letting it write to stdout (for the particularly masochistic)?

Comment: One problem with this is I can't scroll the terminal. (If the text is longer than my terminal height I can't see the top) The text also disappears if I open vim then exit.

Comment: @FDinoff That's what pagers like `less` are there for. Just pipe it into less like so `vim -c ':set t_ti= t_te= nomore' -c 'scriptnames|q!' | less`. The layout maybe screwed up at first (it's in my terminal), but after pressing <C-L> everything is nice and dandy.

Comment: I see no output when running `vim -c ':set t_ti= t_te= nomore' -c 'scriptnames|q!'`, there is only a "quick flash", the command exit with code 0, no output. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `:redir` command to redirect the results of vim commands into a file

For example,

```
vim -c "redir! > vimout | scriptnames | redir END | q"
```

This redirects the output of `scriptnames` into the file "vimout"

Answer (score 2):

For neovim, use

```
nvim --headless -c 'command'
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Your answer was automatically flagged as low-quality due to its length. This answer could be improved with an [edit] to explain how this does the job or why it's different for neovim.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the answer provided by Christian Brabandt but I think a better answer would be to separate the quit command using another -c command like so:

```
vim -c ':set t_ti= t_te= nomore' -c 'scriptnames' -c 'q!'
```

Using this method means that you could string together a number of different commands together and then use the final 'q!' to exit out of vim.

Answer (score 0):

For situations where you need for vim to have fully loaded up as if you started it manually, this works:

```
vim -c "autocmd! CursorHold * <commands to run>"
```

For example, I wanted to redirect the output of `:map` to a file from the shell, but I wanted to capture the mapping that [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) creates only after it's displayed its tabline (line at top showing all buffernames open.)  Because it seems to do this asynchronously, simply running a `-c` redirect to a file wasn't giving it time to make the mappings.  There could be a better way, but this works for me, especially since I already have `updatetime` set to `100` (0.1 seconds), which affects how long until the `CursorHold` event fires.  By default, vim sets it to 4 seconds.

```
vim -c "autocmd! CursorHold * set nomore | redir! > mapNew | map | redir END | q"
```